# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de dos bandas de música en el main de manera automática?

Tags: c, struct

Necesito mostrar los datos de dos bandas de música, indicando nombre de integrantes, rol que cumplen en la banda y un par de canciones; el problema es que NO debe ser ingresado por teclado, sino que debe estar por defecto en mi programa. Lo estoy haciendo con structs.

```c
void bandas_defecto(BA *banda1, BA *banda2)
{
    
    //BANDA COLDPLAY
    strcpy(banda1->nombre_banda,"COLDPLAY");
    strcpy(banda1->pais,"INGLATERRA");
    banda1->cant_miembros=4;
    banda1->cant_canciones=4;
    
    // MIEMBROS DE COLDPLAY
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[0].nombre,"CHRIS MARTIN" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[0].rol,"VOCALISTA" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[0].pais,"INGLATERRA" );
   
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[1].nombre,"GUY BERRYMAN" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[1].rol,"GUITARRISTA" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[1].pais,"ESCOCIA" );
   
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[2].nombre,"JON BUCKLAND" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[2].rol,"GUITARRISTA" );
    strcpy(banda2->integrantes[2].pais,"INGLATERRA" );
    
     //ETCETERA
    
    // CANCIONES DE COLDPLAY
    strcpy(banda2->canciones[0].nombre_cancion,"THE SCIENTIST" );
    banda2->canciones[0].segundos=340;
    banda2->canciones[0].year=2002;
   
    strcpy(banda2->canciones[1].nombre_cancion,"PARADISE" );
    banda2->canciones[1].segundos=297;
    banda2->canciones[1].year=2011;
   
//Necesito solamente llamar esta función del main para ejecutar y mostrar los datos de forma automática.
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] el problema es que NO debe ser ingresado por teclado, sino que debe estar por defecto en mi programa.

Parece que necesitas que los datos hayan sido [persistidos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistencia_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29) en el programa, si todos los datos son conocidos de antemano, puedes escribirlos directamente en el código:

```
Banda bandas[10] =
{
    {"COLDPLAY", "INGLATERRA",
        {
            {"CHRIS MARTIN", "VOCALISTA", "INGLATERRA"},
            {"GUY BERRYMAN", "GUITARRISTA", "ESCOCIA"},
            {"JON BUCKLAND", "GUITARRISTA", "INGLATERRA"}
        },
        {
            {"THE SCIENTIST", 340, 2002},
            {"PARADISE", 297, 2011}
        }
    }
};
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZF/S8JAGMf/3r2Kh0mQYDItiFgF51x2NbfYZiAmcW6XHdhNblsQ4Wu3u2k5IiOCcTee7@d7z6/kKFlQMV@vG1wkizJlcJ4XKc/az5cINVL2xAWDGA@xPw4e@@4VHnkxHFsIFW9LpmTIC1kmBXpHRvJMJYjsZSbZ5Jtjam9lmS32akvK8x/EFRBRsLmk6rT/kbcUOZ8LlkLO5qVIs7wee2NU6hQOFQnPhP3fvvbUbuxKB/71m086lha3SSHZ3FXcqjruUZFSVUx1w0yflQkudEHvphN4/TsPj80WmMQfeDh2wxCbLWQYSjc0cR2SCIY4jImvqfvAwR6JYvzNsmpt@MFoDD0VGasWNDIYkRiH4afDjZzAITv8JvChN3JuPez3f8DrCZRhVSssvnYhcojrxwpW7PGJ1YKuZXU/n77DIe6TyFVa9@xUa51O9QhS30oNRQ0SXigXh68ZT5t6IEupYk@H5kH@IJRtOy9r2t5srWn/gtTX8jfHbl11HhmSFaUUYKkF2uv1Bw)</kbd>.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, lo probare! un abrazo amigo